# Executing javascript contained in HTTP GET response text

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, node.js

I'm using nodejs to make an http GET request that returns a page of JavaScript object definitions that look like the two below . They are contained in the http response text. If I do an eval on the response text I can access the individual objects by name if I know each beforehand, but I can't seem to find a way to dynamically get a list of all the objects created after the eval executes. If this were in a browser I would examine the window object and expect them to be member objects. I've looked at global and module and can't find them in there.

Basically I'm trying to iterate through each object and convert each one to a CSV for loading into a SQL Server database. I have a function that will iterate each one and do the conversion and write a file. I just need to go through X number of objects that could change without notice and do the conversion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var access = { 
PUBLIC: 1 
,REGISTERED: 2 
,VERIFIED: 3 
,WORKER: 4 
,HIDDEN: 5 
,idToObj: { 
    1: { id: 1, name: "PUBLIC", displayName: "Public" } 
    ,2: { id: 2, name: "REGISTERED", displayName: "Registered" } 
    ,3: { id: 3, name: "VERIFIED", displayName: "Verified" } 
    ,4: { id: 4, name: "WORKER", displayName: "Worker" } 
    ,5: { id: 5, name: "HIDDEN", displayName: "Hidden" } 
}}; 
var recommendationType = { 
RECOMMENDED: 1 
,BEST: 2 
,FAVORED: 3 
,idToObj: { 
    1: { id: 1, name: "RECOMMENDED", displayName: "Recommended" } 
    ,2: { id: 2, name: "BEST", displayName: "Best" } 
    ,3: { id: 3, name: "FAVORED", displayName: "Favored" } 
}};
```

Comment: If you have control over the servers you're making requests of, use JSON to return the results instead. It's specifically built for serializing and transmitting such objects.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option. :(